# Looking for Erlang SMPP Client

Tags: erlang, smpp

In my current project I need to connect to SMPP server for transmit SMS's. So I'm looking SMPP clients written in Erlang programming language.

I'm found [OSERL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/oserl/) using [CEAN](http://cean.process-one.net/), but I guess that this project is deprecated (Last Update: 2011-05-25).

Can somebody suggest me modern SMPP clients?

Comment: I use OSERL and I am very happy with it (it is far more stable than the java equivalents). You will probably need something like iconverl to the the character encodings. https://github.com/edescourtis/iconverl

Comment: For gsm0338 encoding you can use something like this https://github.com/edescourtis/gsm0338

Comment: OSERL is still actively developed on github take a look for yourself. https://github.com/edescourtis/oserl/network

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two libraries that claims to support SMPP 3.4 can be found on GitHub, but they do not seem to be actively maintained.

- [Enrique Marcote Peña's SMPP for Erlang](http://github.com/archaelus/oserl)
- [An smpp34 library in Erlang. Built on top of smpp34pdu PDU parsing library](http://github.com/essiene/smpp34)

Answer (score 2):

There are simple library which support SMPP 5.0. Support cyrillic text and gsm 7-bit extension table.

[esmpp_lib](https://github.com/Alex-Zhuk/esmpp_lib)